# Footer is not going doing with content (Vuejs)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, background, footer

Basically I created one component which has just a title and a color for background that should cover the whole page (but it's not, apparently there's a top margin and I don't know how to remove it) and also I created a componenent to be the footer. This component should stay at the botom of the page and it should go down with the addition of content, but it doesn't, the content overlaps it and even crosses it. How can I fix it?

Background CSS:

```
<style scoped>
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
.background{
    position: relative;
    height: 88vh;
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
}
.title{
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    
}
.title h2{
    text-align: left;
    color: #B16DFF;
    padding-top: 0.8em;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Footer CSS:

```
<style scoped>
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  background-color: #232323;
}

.container h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #B16DFF;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
}

.container #text{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5em;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.container p{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
}

.container #title{
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.container #description{
  padding-bottom: 1.3rem;
}

.container #images{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3em;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5em;
}

.container ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your background css, you have a `scoped` style so it doesn't apply to everything.
Also when you use 0 as value for a css property, you don't need to specify units.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll remove the units, thanks. This scoped came standardized with the structure of vue file. I removed it and no changes occurred, so what did you mean by that?

Comment: `<style scoped>` means that it will only render css for this specific component.
The best practise is to declare your global css in your `App.vue` file.
Try this in your `App.vue` global style
```
html, body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: It fixed the problem with that blank space in the top. Thanks! But can this help with the problem of the footer not going down with the addition of other content / components?

Comment: No, if you don't have content, then you will  need to specify a height for your background in px,em,rem, etc... Not in percentage

Comment: Alright. My component is defined with an absolute position (the only way I was able to place it inside the screen). So if I specify the height of my background with another measure, will it adapt to the content?

Comment: You could use 100vh for your background-height. As long as the footer is positioned absolute to the bottom, it won't take any space